# Questions on a plausibility of a Naruto Homage

Tags: fiction, legal, planning

I've been itching to write a web fiction serial that's also a homage to Naruto since I found out the manga ended and went on a re-reading binge... 
Anyway it'll loosely have similar ideas i.e. clans. 
The main three characters are going to be Kamaboko Datemaki, Sakurano Haru, and Sugihara Risuke.

Is that too similar? Would I be sued? I'm planning to keep the end pairings the same but there'll also be a lot of differences especially about the clans. And there might not be Justus at least not like in Naruto.

It might be explained as meta-science and they'll be learning it a University? I really need to think about where I want to go with this. Spent way too much time on the names of everyone's counterparts.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the questions as simply as possible:

Yes it is too similar.

No you won't be sued, with what you're worried about is a cease & desist and no that won't happen either.

And I assume even though there's a question mark at the end of University that's not a question but to be thorough my answer is 'Okay.'